# Implementing an AJAX Pop Up Window

Tags: php, ajax, overlay, popupwindow, modalpopups

I would like to create an AJAX pop up window that will serve as a login pop up when the user clicks "log in" to log in to a website. What algorithm and programming will I need to do this? I will be using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: use jquery's modal popup with $.ajax function

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you need ajax, you can simply have a hidden div that fades in when you click login.

```
<div id="login-trigger">login</div>
<div id="login" style="display:none;">... login form goes here ...</div>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#login-trigger').click(function(){ $('#login').fadeIn() })
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pu4rd/

Comment: Where would I place the jquery code? And would I need more code if I needed to close the window? (An X Button?) Also what about displaying a loading icon (hourglass, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery Tools Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html).
There you can render out a (hidden) div containing the login box and show it as an overlay-popup (or even load an "external" login page like [HERE](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html)).